Unexpected Routes Displayed When Running php artisan route:list in Laravel Project
When I run php artisan route:list in my Laravel project, I see several routes that I did not define in my routes/web.php file. These additional routes seem to be related to Laravel Dusk, Sanctum, and storage.
I need to list the routes which are defined in the routes/web.php
GET|HEAD       _dusk/login/{userId}/{guard?}           dusk.login › Laravel\Dusk\Controllers\...
GET|HEAD       _dusk/logout/{guard?}                  dusk.logout › Laravel\Dusk\Controllers\...
GET|HEAD       _dusk/user/{guard?}                    dusk.user › Laravel\Dusk\Controllers\...
GET|HEAD       email-verification/check/{token}        email-verification.check › ...
GET|HEAD       email-verification/error                email-verification.error › Auth\RegisterController@...
GET|HEAD       sanctum/csrf-cookie                     sanctum.csrf-cookie › Laravel\Sanctum\Http\Controllers...
GET|HEAD       storage/{path}                          ................................ storage.local

Checked routes/web.php: verified that none of these routes are defined here.

That because Starter Kits. On User  model do you have the extends Authenticatable implements MustVerifyEmail ? remove that for extends Model and will not use that routes

I install the breeze package is that might be the case

yeah, that pack publishes the authentication views, routes, controllers, and other resources to your application, you can remove by : composer remove laravel/breeze

Thank you I removed them.After that also I listed the routes it gives me the same above. Do I need to remove the controllers which were created by them also.

check if composer update  & php artisan optimize:clear solves

Still it gives the same results. in the Http/Controllers/Auth do we need to delete the files like RegisteredUserController like generated controllers.

yeah, since it publish the files on your workspace, now you need to remove it from controllers, requests, views, middleware (EnsureEmailIsVerified), test (tests/Feature/Auth/PasswordConfirmationTest) etc.. You can check all that here  what have been created and needs to be removed

EnsureEmailIsVerified can you explain it little bit more. I removed the files but it didn't work.

EnsureEmailIsVerified ( Illuminate\Auth\Middleware\EnsureEmailIsVerified)  is a middleware that then verifies this: ! $request->user() ||             ($request->user() instanceof MustVerifyEmail &&             ! $request->user()->hasVerifiedEmail()), if you have on model User with  the interface MustVerifyEmail it will check...Do you have like Auth::routes(['verify' => true]);? change to false.

Since you have added a Starter Kits, named breeze, you can remove it by:
composer remove laravel/breeze
Since removing from the vendor don't remove the workspace, you need to remove them manually, check the files to remove here.

Yes I removed it. After that also it gives me the same routes. Do I need to remove the manually the controller created in auth/ due to breeze?

Why it is blocking my routes in the we.php

Try search for the name of the routes email-verification.error and email-verification.error where it is defined these routes and remove them to show on web

if you want to check all routes defined by you . you can filter it out by middleware

i have shared the command  try this and check 

php artisan route:list --middleware=web


error: The "--middleware" option does not exist.

Yes it gives the same error for me

middleware not assigned yet to your route try this this may help
command -   php artisan route:list | findstr /v "auth login register password logout"

To list routes that are not defined by vendor packages:
php artisan route:list --except-vendor

This might help

This gives two route GET|HEAD       email-verification/check/{token} email-verification.check › …   GET|HEAD       email-verification/error email-verification.error › Auth\Reg…but none of them are in the web.php file.
